# Query selector for the individual buttons in range selector

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I want the individual buttons from the range selector of highcharts. The following gives me all the buttons.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-button')
```

I tried to set className for along with type, text, and count but that dint help.
I wanted a className or id that distinguishes all range selector buttons from each other how do I do that.

Comment: Not sure I understand the situation. So you have a bunch of buttons with class `highcharts-button`. And you want to give them all unique Ids?

Comment: @codemonkey Yes, you got it correct. Another accepted way was to get the individual buttons for query selection somehow. The problem is these buttons are defined in the Highchart library and the only way I set these buttons is through available properties. Please check this for reference. https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/rangeselector/datagrouping/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below demo where you can find a way how to get an array of range selector buttons.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g2z9b1fy/

```
// Create the chart
var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
});

console.log(chart.rangeSelector.buttons)
```

Comment: what if I am wanted to apply different styling to each button. Since currently there is no unique id or class name on each element I cannot achieve that.

Comment: You can add the inline styling: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6qm3envu/

Comment: Hi, my customer needs to access buttons. So above isn't feasible for me. I tried to set the id as follows. The console in script prints it but document.getElementByID in inspector doesn't print it.
              $.each(chart.rangeSelector.buttons, function (i, button) {
                  var rectInButton = button.element.childNodes[1];
                  var textInRect = button.element.childNodes[2];
                  rectInButton.setAttribute("id", textInRect.innerHTML);
                  console.log(rectInButton)
              });
ref : http://jsfiddle.net/Delfin_/yna97mrp/1/